# Requirements for use of CUDA-aware MPI

Tags: c++, c, cuda, mpi

I would like to exchange data between different CUDA-devices by means of CUDA-aware MPI as described in [this article](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/introduction-cuda-aware-mpi/). As I understand it, the following code ought to do the job:

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  int rank;
  float *ptr = NULL;
  const size_t elements = 32;
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init( NULL, NULL );
  MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
  cudaMalloc( (void**)&ptr, elements * sizeof(float) );

  if( rank == 0 )
    MPI_Send( ptr, elements, MPI_FLOAT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
  if( rank == 1 )
    MPI_Recv( ptr, elements, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );

  cudaFree( ptr );
  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this program crashed with a segfault when executed on two processes, giving the following message:

```
*** Process received signal ***
Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
Failing at address: 0x210000
[ 0] /lib64/libc.so.6[0x39d94326a0]
[ 1] /lib64/libc.so.6(memcpy+0xd2)[0x39d9489742]
[ 2] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.6(opal_convertor_pack+0x18e)[0x2b750326cb1e]
[ 3] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_smcuda.so(mca_btl_smcuda_sendi+0x3dc)[0x2b7507c2252c]
[ 4] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(+0x890f)[0x2b75086ec90f]
[ 5] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_send+0x499)[0x2b75086ed939]
[ 6] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(PMPI_Send+0x1dd)[0x2b7502d3ef8d]
[ 7] prog(main+0x98)[0x400d51]
[ 8] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x39d941ed5d]
[ 9] prog[0x400be9]
*** End of error message ***
```

I use OpenMPI 1.8.2 and nvcc 6.5; as far as I know, these versions are supposed to support this feature.

So, my question is: What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some point? I would very much appreciate any hints at how to obtain a **minimal working example**!

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable in this, but as per simple logic, why din't you check for the success of allocation in `cudaMalloc()` or is it not required?

Comment: I checked that and found that this is not the problem. In general I agree that a check is a good idea, but here I simply tried to keep the code short.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll just summarize the discussion in a concise answer. The code is correct, but the following issues might arrise:

1. MPI has not been **built with CUDA support** (see answer by @Robert Crovella). This can be checked by invoking:

   `ompi_info --parsable -l 9 --all | grep mpi_built_with_cuda_support:value`

   which, in case, everything is fine, ought to give:

   `mca:mpi:base:param:mpi_built_with_cuda_support:value:true`
2. The **architecture** of the GPUs does not support the feature. Fermi or later is needed (see comment by @Christian Sarofeen)

It turned out the second problem applied to my situation.

Answer (score 6):

The segfault is almost certainly due to passing a device pointer to MPI, when MPI is expecting a host pointer. Only properly built CUDA-aware MPI can accept the device pointer. It's not enough simply to have OpenMPI 1.8.2. You must have an OpenMPI version that is explicitly built with the CUDA-aware settings.

For OpenMPI,

Start [here](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#build-cuda)

Excerpting:

34. How do I build Open MPI with CUDA-aware support?

CUDA-aware support means that the MPI library can send and receive GPU buffers directly. This feature exists in the Open MPI 1.7 series and later. The support is being continuously updated so different levels of support exist in different versions.

> Configuring Open MPI 1.7, MPI 1.7.1 and 1.7.2

```
--with-cuda(=DIR)       Build cuda support, optionally adding DIR/include,
                      DIR/lib, and DIR/lib64


--with-cuda-libdir=DIR  Search for cuda libraries in DIR
```

Here are some examples of configure commands that enable CUDA support.

1. Searches in default locations. Looks for cuda.h in /usr/local/cuda/include and libcuda.so in /usr/lib64.

   ```
   ./configure --with-cuda
   ```
2. Searches for cuda.h in /usr/local/cuda-v4.0/cuda/include and libcuda.so in default location of /usr/lib64.

   ```
   ./configure --with-cuda=/usr/local/cuda-v4.0/cuda
   ```
3. Searches for cuda.h in /usr/local/cuda-v4.0/cuda/include and libcuda.so in /usr/lib64. (same as previous one)

   ```
   ./configure --with-cuda=/usr/local/cuda-v4.0/cuda --with-cuda-libdir=/usr/lib64
   ```

If the cuda.h or libcuda.so files cannot be found, then the configure will abort.

Note: There is a bug in Open MPI 1.7.2 such that you will get an error if you configure the library with --enable-static. To get around this error, add the following to your configure line and reconfigure. This disables the build of the PML BFO which is largely unused anyways. This bug is fixed in Open MPI 1.7.3.

```
--enable-mca-no-build=pml-bfo
```

> Configuring Open MPI 1.7.3 and later

With Open MPI 1.7.3 and later the libcuda.so library is loaded dynamically so there is no need to specify a path to it at configure time. Therefore, all you need is the path to the cuda.h header file.

1. Searches in default locations. Looks for cuda.h in /usr/local/cuda/include.

   ```
   ./configure --with-cuda
   ```
2. Searches for cuda.h in /usr/local/cuda-v5.0/cuda/include.

   ```
   ./configure --with-cuda=/usr/local/cuda-v5.0/cuda
   ```

Note that you cannot configure with `--disable-dlopen` as that will break the ability of the Open MPI library to dynamically load libcuda.so.

See

[this FAQ entry](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#mpi-cuda-support) for details on how to use the CUDA support.

Note that these instructions assume some familiarity with building OpenMPI.  It's not enough simply to run `./configure ...`  There are make and make install steps after that.  But the above configuration commands are what differentiate a CUDA-aware OpenMPI build from an ordinary one.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the MPI implementation I use was built with CUDA support (`ompi_info --parsable -l 9 --all | grep mpi_built_with_cuda_support:value` gives `mca:mpi:base:param:mpi_built_with_cuda_support:value:true`), so this is not the problem.

Comment: I tried to run the program on another (much newer) device (Tesla K40) with basically the same software environment. There it works! My first, unsuccessful try was on Tesla T10 cards. Any explanation for that? Does it have to do with the compute capability?

Comment: Yes, it needs Fermi or later. "GPUDirect  peer-to-peer transfers and memory access are supported natively by the CUDA Driver. All you need is CUDA Toolkit v4.0 and R270 drivers (or later) and a system with two or more Fermi- or Kepler-architecture GPUs on the same PCIe bus." https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect