# Can I use cudaMemcpyPeer to transfer data between different gpus assigned by MPI?

Tags: cuda, mpi

I use mpi to generate multiple processes, each process corresponds to a gpu device. I used MPI_Send to transfer data before, but its speed is too slow.

I found that the transfer speed using cudaMemcpyPeer is very fast, but I don’t know if I can use cudaMemcpyPeer or cudaMemcpyPeerAsync to transfer data in the MPI environment.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this case is to use CUDA-aware MPI.   It is a special version of MPI that understands CUDA usage.  In particular it allows you to use CUDA device pointers as buffer pointers in calls such as MPI_Send, MPI_Recv, and MPI_SendRecv, and will use the fastest possible means provided by CUDA (such as peer transfers between 2 GPUs, in the same machine, when possible) to do the data movement.

Various MPI distributions such as [OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=buildcuda) and [MVAPICH](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/userguide/gdr/) have CUDA-enabled versions.

You can find more info about it by reading [this blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/introduction-cuda-aware-mpi/).  You can also find questions about it here on the `cuda` tag such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908813/requirements-for-use-of-cuda-aware-mpi).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am using CUDA-aware MPI to transfer data right now. This method is a little slower than cudaMemcpyPeer to pass double data, but it is very slow to pass my custom data structures, which is why I want to use cudaMemcpyPeer .